# に/で and を/から - particle choice in two JLPT N5 sentences

Tags: grammar, particles, jlpt

> この　かみ**に**　電話番号を　書いてください。

Why is it wrong to use で instead? What if the sentence is like このボールペン＿＿電話番号を書いてください?

> 六時に　会社**を**　出て、うちへ　帰ります。

Why is it wrong to use から here? Is it because it's a fixed expression?

Comment: These are two questions! It might be more useful if you split this into two separate questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First question about で: かみに means "**on** the paper" ("write on the paper") while かみで would mean "**with** the paper" in a sense "using a tool" as in "write with a pen". So your second sentence requires で:

> このボールペンで電話番号を書いてください

Second question about から: when you go **out** of a location, you use を particle in this situation, not から. Note that から is used as well in every day life depending on the situation but at JLPT 5 level, を will be used in your textbook and exercises.

Comment: I might be over thinking this. But what is I want to say "Please type in your phone number (on my phone)?" 私の携帯に電話番号を入力してください？

Comment: Yes, に in this case as well. What is confusing you here?

Comment: We say 「(Place)から出る」 all the time.  You make it sound like we never do.  It is just that in OP's context, it is "better" to use を.

Comment: @非回答者 Thanks for the comment. I updated my answer - hope it's better now. Let me know if I should reword it further.